# is it legal to take the address of an union member in C?

Tags: c, unions

I want to do something like this:

```
union U {
    int i;
    double d;
};

void foo (double *d) { *d = 3.4; }

int main ()
{
     union U u;
     foo (&(u.d));
}
```

`gcc` does not complain (with `-Wall -Wextra`) and it works as expected, but I would like to make sure it is actually legal (according to the standard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be legal? Actually, it's even guaranteed that the addresses of every member is equal to the address of whole union:

> A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members [...] and vice versa.

(C11, §6.7.2.1 16)

(which implies that you *can* take a pointer to union members)

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is legal, and there would be no reason for it not to be. Simple as that.

Comment: On many compilers, the behavior of dereferencing a pointer to &u.d is inconsistent with the behavior of accessing u.d directly, in ways that from what I can tell would imply that either (1) the target of &u.d isn't really an object of type `double`, so using a pointer of type (double*) to access that object is UB and compilers can do whatever they want, or (2) compilers routinely violate the Standard.  Can you offer any other explanation for such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

C99:

> 6.5.3.2
>
> **Address and indirection operators**
>
> Constraints
>
> 1. The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result
>      of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object
>      that is not a bit-ﬁeld and is not declared with the register
>      storage-class speciﬁer

[...]

> **object**
>    region of data storage in the execution environment, the
>   contents of which can represent values

So, yes, a union is an object and therefore may be an operand of & as long as it meets the other requirements.