# How to copy anonymous union

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unions

I have an anonymous union in a struct

```
struct A {
  union {
    char c;
    double d;
  };
  A(const A &a) {
    c = a.c;
    d = a.d;
  }
};
```

I was wondering what is the best way to define its copy constructor.
Do we have to copy all union fields? I guess we have to ...?

Comment: Only one data member of a union has a value at any one time. Which data member holds a value is normally indicated by a *discriminant* (an object) contained within the class. Copy constructors would make use of this discriminant.

Comment: I would use `memcpy(&c, &a.c, sizeof(union{char c;double d;}));`, perhaps with a `typedef` type for the `union`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, will c and d always locate from the same address?

Comment: @JoeC [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15444631/335858)

Answer (score 4):

Remember that only one union field at a time can be active. To copy a union, you just need to copy whichever one of them is active.

Generally, when using unions like this, you'll have some sort of "tag" field keeping track of which field is active. You can then use a `switch` statement on that tag to determine which field is the active one and how to copy it over.

Alternatively, consider using `boost::variant`, which is a type-safe wrapper around an object of one of a fixed number of types.

Comment: This is some legacy code w/o tags. If we copy all the fields, although only one is active, will the copy make the other non-active ones have incorrect value? I think internally all data are stored as raw bits, there should be no runtime non-noop cast at runtime. But I am not sure if this is safe...

Comment: I believe that it's undefined behavior to read from a field of a union that was not the last one read from, so this would not be safe.

Comment: If we do nothing, does a compiler generate a default copy-constructor? I think it does not know which one is active, can the default constructor work in a defined behavior?

Comment: I don't think that anonymous unions work that way. If you made the union an actual type, that might work!